# HTML2PDF page stores file but is not sent in e-mail

Tags: php, phpmailer, html2pdf

i have a problem with my code, it's supposed to store the pdf file in the server and then send it as an attachment in an e-mail to the client automatically, here is the code :

```
ob_end_clean(); 
$fileName='CW00'.$commande.'.pdf';
$file = $html2pdf>Output('/home/itscoma/public_html/components/'.$fileName,'F');
try{
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->Host= "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 0;                 
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;         
$mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;
$mail->Port = 465;                  
$mail->Username   = "***@***.com";
$mail->Password   = "******";
$mail->From='a***@gmail.com';
$mail->AddAddress('*****@gmail.com');
$mail->AddReplyTo('*****@gmail.com');   
$mail->Subject='sujet';
$mail->Body='message';
$mail->AddAttachment($file);
$mail->Send();
unset($mail);
} catch (Exception $e) {

  echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";

}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?
Is the file stored in the server? Did you go to the save location and verified the file is present?

Comment: And for the love of god do not put your passwords here in a public forum!

Answer (score 0):

Several things wrong here. This combination will not work:

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;
$mail->Port = 465;
```

Change `Port` to 587 to use that encryption mode, *or* change encryption mode to `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` to work with port 465.

This line is meaningless:

```
$file = $html2pdf>Output('/home/itscoma/public_html/components/'.$fileName,'F');
```

because you're missing a `-`, it should be `$html2pdf->Output`.

Next, what does that method return? What do you get in `$file`? If it's not the path to the saved file (which you already know anyway), then passing it to `addAttachment` is not going to do anything useful. It would be a good idea to check that this call actually works – at the moment you're just assuming it does.

You would know this if you checked the return value from `addAttachment()`, but you're not so you don't know that it's failing.

I suggest trying this:

```
if (!$mail->addAttachment('/home/itscoma/public_html/components/' . $fileName)) {
    echo 'Attachment failed';
}
```